# How do I import information from member of Facebook ...?

Tags: facebook

How do I import information from member of Facebook and print the in the registration form on my website
I want to import
Name
E-mail
Personal Photo

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a short answer to this question, so instead I suggest you start reading the guide

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web